# dropdown menu in html using bootstrap navbar not working for some reason

Tags: html, navbar, dropdown

So the title is pretty straight forward, i tried to find the mistake but cannot see it, please if anyone could help. Thank you

Here is the code:

```
<header>      
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="menu-1">
    <div class="navbarheader">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand pull-left" href="index.html">
      <img alt="Logo" src="img/logoedit3.png" class="img-responsive" id="logo">
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></i></b>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></li>
                <li><a href="demolition.html">Demolition</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a href="employers.html">Employers</a></li>
          <li><a href="employees.html">Employees</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is causing the problem I have put boostrap.js after jquery.js
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Missing

```
</a>
```

in:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></i></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works. See below examples. Something else is wrong with your code. Perhaps it is just a z-index problem.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6oytw42p/)</kbd>

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>      
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="menu-1">
    <div class="navbarheader">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand pull-left" href="index.html">
      <img alt="Logo" src="img/logoedit3.png" class="img-responsive" id="logo">
      </a>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></i></b>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></li>
                <li><a href="demolition.html">Demolition</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a href="employers.html">Employers</a></li>
          <li><a href="employees.html">Employees</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: hm, thats really strange, it works on here even without the closing </a> but it does not work with my code. I will just paste the whole code below

Comment: I cant, its longer than it is allowed. I will post just bellow the header:

Comment: <footer class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p class="navbar-text pull-left">&copy; DSM Services Ltd</p>
  <div class="navbar-text pull-right" id="social-icons">
    <a href="linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
    <a href="twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
    </footer>  
  </div>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure how to post the code properly as a comment.

Comment: I found out what is causing the problem I have put <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> after <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> and that was causing the problem

Comment: Modify your original question. Add three dashes (---) on a line by themselves, and note that you are adding additional code. Paste code and save the modified question

Comment: Well done. Glad you solved it.  Create an answer (yes, answer your own question) and post the solution inside it. You will not be able to select it as correct answer until tomorrow, but remember to come back and do that. Glad you solved it.

Comment: I will correct it however it doesn't allow me to edit it, I clicked on edit it but when trying to press enter to go to the next like I think i blocked editing for 5 minutes, I saw a message like that. I also did post an answer but it does not show for some reason, I will try again. Thank for the tips

Comment: Hmmmm. You might not have sufficient rep (points) to edit your question. Been a while since I had a new account, so I don't recall. Answer a few questions for beginners and you'll have the rep soon enough. :) Weekends and Fri/Sat evenings are a good time to find unanswered beginner questions.